# Parsing mixed text file with a lot header info

Tags: python

I'm an amateur astronomer (and retired) and just messing around with an idea.  I want to scrape data from a NASA website that is a text file and extract specific values to help me identify when to observe.  The text file automatically updates every 60 seconds. The text file has some header information before the actual rows and columns of data that I need to process. The actual data is numerical.  Example:

Prepared by NASA

Please send comments and suggestions to xxx.com

Date  Time  Year

yr mo da    hhmm   day   value1    value2

---

2019 03 31  1933   234   6.00e-09    1.00e-09

I want to access the string numerical data and convert it into a double

From what I can see the file is space delimited

I want to poll the website every 60 seconds and if Value 1 and Value 2 are above a specific threshold that will trigger a PyAutoGUI to automate a software application to take an image.

After reading the file from the website I tried converting the file into a dictionary thinking that I could then map keys to values, but I can't predict the exact location that I need. I thought once I extract the values I need I would write the file then try to convert the string into a double or float

I have tried to use

```
import re
re.split
```

to read each line and split out info but I get a huge mess because of the header information

I wanted to use a simple approach to open the file and this works

```
import urllib
import csv

data = urllib.urlopen("https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-xray-flux-primary.txt").read()

print (data)
```

I found this on Stack overflow but I don't understand how I would use this

```
file = open('abc.txt','r')
while 1:
    a = file.readline()
    if a =='': break
    a = a.split()                  #This creates a list of the input
    name = a[0]
    value = int(a[1])              # or value=float(a[1]) whatever you want
    #use the name and value howsoever
f.close()
```

What I want is it to extract Value 1 and Value 2 as a double or float than in Part II (which I have not yet even started) I will compare Value 1 and Value 2 and if they are about a specific threshold this would trigger a PyAutoGUI to interact with my imaging software and trigger taking an image.

Comment: I think your general approach should be to read past the header data before starting your real processing.  You could, for example, read lines until you get the **"Date Time Year"** line, if you can count on that always being there. - This is a great use case for regular expressions.  But maybe you don't know enough about them to want to use them here.  That's what's fun about programming.  Lots of ways to skin the cat! - or maybe I mean look for **"yr mo da hhmm day value1 value2"**, if that's what's literally in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun little challenge, I've pulled all the data out of the table for you, mapped it to class and converted the data to `int` and `Decimal` as appropriate. Once it's populated you can read all the data you want from it.

To get the data I've used the requests library, instead of `urllib`, that's merely personal preference. You could use `pip install requests`, if you wanted to use it too. It has a method `iter_lines` that can traverse the rows of data.

This may be overkill for what you need, but as I wrote it anyway I thought I'd post it for you.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

import requests


class SolarXrayFluxData:
    def __init__(
            self,
            year,
            month,
            day,
            time,
            modified_julian_day,
            seconds_of_the_day,
            short,
            long
    ):
        self.date = datetime(
            int(year), int(month), int(day), hour=int(time[:2]), minute=int(time[2:])
        )
        self.modified_julian_day = int(modified_julian_day)
        self.seconds_of_the_day = int(seconds_of_the_day)
        self.short = Decimal(short)
        self.long = Decimal(long)


class GoesXrayFluxPrimary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.created_at = ''
        self.data = []

    def extract_data(self, url):
        data = requests.get(url)
        for i, line in enumerate(data.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True)):
            if line[0] in [':', '#']:
                if i is 1:
                    self.set_created_at(line)
                continue

            row_data = re.findall(r"(\S+)", line)
            self.data.append(SolarXrayFluxData(*row_data))

    def set_created_at(self, line):
        date_str = re.search(r'\d{4}\s\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}', line).group(0)
        self.created_at = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y %b %d %H%M')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    goes_xray_flux_primary = GoesXrayFluxPrimary()
    goes_xray_flux_primary.extract_data('https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-xray-flux-primary.txt')
    print("Created At: %s" % goes_xray_flux_primary.created_at)
    for row in goes_xray_flux_primary.data:
        print(row.date)
        print("%.12f, %.12f" % (row.short, row.long))
```

The intention of the `SolarXrayFluxData` class is to store each items data and to make sure it is in a nice usable format. While the `GoesXrayFluxPrimary` class is used populate a list of `SolarXrayFluxData` and to store any other data that you might want to pull out. For example I've grabbed the `Created` date and time. You could also get the `Location` and `Source` from the header data.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will spend the rest of the day dissecting what you have done with my Python cookbook in hand.  I hope you don't mind but I probably have a few questions about what and why you did once I do my homework and thoroughly look at your code.

Comment: If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example of using regular expressions.  This assumes you'd read the whole file into memory with a single `f.read()` rather that bothering to process individual lines, which with regular expressions, is often the simpler way to go (and I'm lazy and didn't want to have to create a test file):

```
import re

data = """
blah
blah

yr mo da hhmm day value1 value2

2019 03 31 1933 234 6.00e-09 1.00e-09

blah
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)")

def main():
    m = pattern.search(data)
    if m:
        # Do whatever processing you want to do here.  You have access to all 7 input
        # fields via m.group(1-7)
        d1 = float(m.group(6))
        d2 = float(m.group(7))
        print(">{}< >{}<".format(d1, d2))
    else:
        print("no match")

main()
```

Output:

```
>6e-09< >1e-09<
```

You'd want to tweak this a bit if I've made a wrong assumption about the input data, but this gives you the general idea anyway.

This should handle just about anything else that exists in the input as long as nothing else does that looks like that one line you're interested in.

UPDATE:

I can't leave well enough alone.  Here's code that pulls the data from the URL you provide and processes all the matching lines:

```
import re
import urllib

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)")

def main():

    data = urllib.urlopen("https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-xray-flux-primary.txt").read()

    pos = 0
    while True:
        m = pattern.search(data, pos)
        if not m:
            break
        pos = m.end()
        # Do whatever processing you want to do here.  You have access to all 8 input
        # fields via m.group(1-8)
        f1 = float(m.group(7))
        f2 = float(m.group(8))
        print(">{}< >{}<".format(f1, f2))

main()
```

Result:

```
>9.22e-09< >1e-09<
>1.06e-08< >1e-09<
...
>8.99e-09< >1e-09<
>1.01e-08< >1e-09<
```

Comment: `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)` may be a better choice because it will "return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string"

Comment: That's mostly a style choice in this case.  I already deal with overlapping by moving the position past each match.  The downside of **findall** is that you get in trouble with more complex expressions, where not all groups always match.  I go with **search** as a general rule so I do things the same way regardless of how complex the expression is. - another way to say this is with **findall**, you lose access to the match object itself. - I do agree that in this case, **findall** would work equally well, and might even make the post-processing a bit simpler.

Comment: Hey @Walter, did this give you what you need?  Do you need any additional help?  I can't tell if you're one of the upvotes here.  The **checkmark** is for you.  If this answered your question, you should click the **checkmark** to make it green so everyone can know you got an answer you liked.  (btw, I don't care about the extra 5 points.  I really am interested in if the OP got what he wanted from this)

Comment: Hello Steve, yes this has helped me immensely! I will have to go over what you have written line by line with my Python cookbook in hand.  I don't want what you have done to be a 'black magic' box of code for me.  42 years ago in college, I took a Fortran class and over the last month I have been playing around with Python.  All of the Python references are helpful for me learning to code simple projects. Now I have to wrap my head around how to put all the discrete things I have learned into larger applications. Thank you again! Walter

Comment: You're very welcome.  The only tricky bit here, I'd hope, would be the regular expression itself. That's something you either want to delve into or not.  I'm a "regular expression weenie".  I consider them to be one of the Holy Grails of programming.  So I'd highly recommend that you understand this particular expression, at least.  I can explain it to you if you'd like.

Comment: ...and btw, I'm an old timer.  My first programming class was in Fortran on punch cards.  I came in just at the tail end of that era, and never again had to endure such torture.